# Java, SOLR: How to exclude method or create new solr folder for Junit tests

Tags: java, solr, junit, filter, annotations

My server-client project uses SOLR and i have a addToSolrServer(obj o) method in my class PersonSolrEventHandler(this class is annotated as @Component).
This method gets called when i add (through webservice) a person to my external database and also adds my testdata/persons to the SOLR-database.
How can i exclude that method from Junit testing? SOLR should not add any testdata to the database while Junit testing. I would like to add a new directory for junit tests (e.g. data/solr/person-junit/index/ instead of my current solr folder data/solr/person/index/)

for example:
is it possible to write a solr-junit.xml with the new /person-junit/index folder in it and call it when junit tests get executed?

im a student and this is my first project in a company...so i appreciate any hint or guideline.

thanks

Comment: How are you testing ? Manual or Automated Unit tests ? If Unit tests use Mocking.

Comment: another way to solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495999/exclude-filter-for-a-component-class-while-junit-testing