# Exclude-filter for a @Component class while JUnit testing?

Tags: java, spring, junit, filter, annotations

is it possible to exclude a `@Component` annotated class?

i would like to exclude a special class from JUnit testing.

my project has a class `xEventHandler` annotated with `@Component` and i dont want spring to use this class while junit testing.

my ApplicationTestContext.xml looks like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company">
...
<context:exclude-filter expression="com\.company\.xyz\.xEventHandler.java " type="regex"/>
...
</context:component-scan>
```

however, the class gets entered because of the `@Component` annotation(e.g. works, when i delete the `@Component` from that class).

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should just be:

```
<context:exclude-filter expression="com\.company\.xyz\.xEventHandler" type="regex"/>
```

Comment: yea right...i entered the xEventHandler.java(which is the file). thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it is better to use profiles (introduced in 3.1) to achieve this:

- define this bean inside `test` profile
- activate `test` profile in JUnit test by adding `@ActiveProfiles("test")` annotation

More information about profiles:

- http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/
- http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/08/using-spring-profiles-in-xml-config.html